# Pushing content to twitter, facebook and linkedin using Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, twitter, linkedin-api

Hi I am working on web application using Codeigniter.

I have a small module where when we will publish some news it needs to be published to social networking websites like twitter, facebook and linkedin.

I was wondering if there are any simple CI libraries available to deal with all three. or any sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So far i use [facebook php sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and i put it on 'third party' folder, then i make my own library to wrap this sdk . (You can call it by $this->the_library->youfunction_wrapper($you_parameters) ). I prefer this method since once the sdk is 'upgraded' you should only replace the old sdk with the new one.

try to consider thesee one :

1. [Facebook library](https://github.com/bugzbrown/codeigniter-facebook-lib)
2. [TwitterOauth](https://github.com/MunGell/Codeigniter-TwitterOAuth) <-- i recomend you to read the entire example code on how mungell wrap '3rd' party sdk to codeigniter . Compare it with the original implementation on [abraham's twitter php library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I doesnt have to be CI. I dont mind if it can be done in simple PHP.